# Как построить диаграмму рассеивания из двух списков?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib, scatter

Есть два списка данных `time` и `value`, уже посчитанные в Python.

```
time

[214400,
 212100,
 115700,
 100100,
 180400,
 104300,
 103000,
 112300,
 100100]

value

[157460,
 162960,
 165450,
 159740,
 153490,
 153290,
 154930,
 136830,
 104000]
```

Как из этих двух списков построить диаграмму рассеивания? (картинка просто как пример)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а вы можете еще и ваш код как пример?

Comment: @ЛеонидВ Ладно, восстановил и чуть дополнил )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А в чём сложность?

```
from matplotlib import pylab as plt

time =\
[214400,
 212100,
 115700,
 100100,
 180400,
 104300,
 103000,
 112300,
 100100]

value =\
[157460,
 162960,
 165450,
 159740,
 153490,
 153290,
 154930,
 136830,
 104000]

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5)); # если нужно задать размер картинки
plt.scatter(time, value);
```

Хотел ещё картинку приложить, но какие-то сложности с браузером.

`;` в конце строк отрисовки нужна, чтобы Jupyter не писал лишнего в выводе (он выводит на экран репрезентацию того, что возвращает последняя инструкция в ячейке, там будет всякая лабуда на экране помимо графика).

Comment: `; в конце строк отрисовки нужна, чтобы Jupyter не писал лишнего в выводе` - не знал о такой "фиче", спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def scatterplot(x_data, y_data, 
                x_label="x_label", y_label="y_label", 
                title="Hello World", 
                color = "r", 
                yscale_log=False
               ):

    # Create the plot object
    _, ax = plt.subplots()

    # Plot the data, set the size (s), color and transparency (alpha)
    # of the points
    ax.scatter(x_data, y_data, s = 10, color = color, alpha = 0.75)

    if yscale_log == True:
        ax.set_yscale('log')

    # Label the axes and provide a title
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xlabel(x_label)
    ax.set_ylabel(y_label)
    
    plt.show()
    

a = [214400, 212100, 115700, 100100, 180400, 104300, 103000, 112300, 100100]
b = [157460, 162960, 165450, 159740, 153490, 153290, 154930, 136830, 104000]

scatterplot(a, b)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ЛеонидВ это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: @ЛеонидВ что мешает написать вместо `_, ax = plt.subplots()` - `_, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))`?